# Set firebase storage security rules to public

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am new in firebase, so the question that i want to ask is how to set firebase security rules as public. Anyone know the code?

Here is the security rules of my firebase now:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't entirely clear on what "set firebase security rules as public" specifically means.  Your rules already allow full public read access to your default storage bucket.  If you want to also allow full public write access, simply remove the condition from the "allow write" line.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

This is generally a bad idea, as it allows anyone with an internet connection to fully modify and delete anything and everything in your storage bucket.  If you want to learn how to correctly use security rules, you should start with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/get-started).